# How to write a for loop to merge all the nth columns of files in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

In the second line of the code, I'm attempting to merge all the `*.out.tab` files by columns.
The third line of the code extracts the **first** column and every **4th** subsequent columns (4th, 8th, 12th, 16th...), meaning every fourth column of each file.

Without a for loop, it would be like...

```
paste 1.out.tab 2.out.tab 3.out.tab 4.out.tab \
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=4){printf "%s ",$i;} print ""}' | \
tail -n +5 > tmpfile
cat tmpfile | sed "s/^ENSG*//" >gene_count.txt
```

However, now I want to use a for loop to merge all the files.

```
for f in `./alignments/repaired_reads/*ReadsPerGene.out.tab | sed 's/.ReadsPerGene.out.tab//'`;
paste "$f"\.out.tab | \
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=4){printf "%s ",$i;} print ""}' | \
tail -n +5 > tmpfile
cat tmpfile | sed "s/^ENSG*://" > gene_count.txt
```

Sample input:

```
head ./alignments/repaired_reads/SRR9200814ReadsPerGene.out.tab

N_unmapped  18517   18517   18517
N_multimapping  1620    1620    1620
N_noFeature 8046    33145   33275
N_ambiguous 5860    1201    1034
ENSG00000160072 0   0   0
ENSG00000279928 0   0   0
ENSG00000228037 0   0   0
ENSG00000142611 0   0   0
ENSG00000284616 0   0   0
ENSG00000157911 0   0   0

head ./alignments/repaired_reads/SRR9200815ReadsPerGene.out.tab

N_unmapped  124416  124416  124416
N_multimapping  19165   19165   19165
N_noFeature 40924   384454  392595
N_ambiguous 99220   21834   20712
ENSG00000160072 0   0   0
ENSG00000279928 0   0   0
ENSG00000228037 0   0   0
ENSG00000142611 35  22  13
ENSG00000284616 0   0   0
ENSG00000157911 24  22  8
```

Desired output:

```
N_unmapped   18517  124416
N_multimapping   1620  19165
N_noFeature     33275  392595
N_ambiguous  1034  20712
ENSG00000160072     0  0
ENSG00000279928  0  0
ENSG00000228037  0  0
ENSG00000142611  0  13
ENSG00000284616  0  0
ENSG00000157911  0  8
```

Comment: why does your `sed` script reference `^gene:` where no such string exists in the data?

Comment: is the 1st column guaranteed to be unique within a file?

Comment: @markp-fuso sorry the `sed` should take `ENSG*` instead of `^gene`

Comment: @markp-fuso I changed it to `for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=4)`

Comment: Yes, the first column is unique within file

Comment: still have the issue ... `^ENSG*:` (note the trailing colon) does not show up in the data

Comment: I want to get the first column before I get every 4th columns. Should `i=4`? I expect `ENSG*` to match on all the values in the first column that begin with ENSG, for example `ENSG00000160072`, `ENSG00000279928`, `ENSG00000228037`

Comment: The trailing colon in `^ENSG*:` is not needed. It should be `^ENSG*`. My mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. This will make sure order of $1(first field) is same as per their presence. This will create output file named `gene_count.txt` and it will read multiple files as input.

```bash
awk '
!presence[$1]++{
  arr[++max]=$1
}
{
  for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=4){
    maxValue[$1]=(maxValue[$1]>$i?maxValue[$1]:$i)
  }
  overAllMax[$1]=(overAllMax[$1]?overAllMax[$1] OFS:"") maxValue[$1]
}
END{
  for(j=1;j<=max;j++){
    print arr[j],overAllMax[arr[j]]
  }
}
' *ReadsPerGene.out.tab > gene_count.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

- Using an array named `presence` with index of $1 and checking if its occurrence is NOT present then make an entry in it and then:
- Create an array named `arr` with index of `max` variable with increasing value of it, assigning value to `arr` as $1.
- Starting a `for` loop to go through every 4th, 8th, 12th and every 4th field in each line.
- Creating an array named `maxValue` with index of `$1` and keeping only MAX value here Only by checking condition with Ternary operators.
- Creating an array named `overAllMax` which will have all similar first fields all Maximum values keep appending to it, to get overall max values basically.
- In `END` block of this program going through from `1` to till value of `max` to print all values.
- Inside loop printing values of `arr[j]`(which is `$1`) and value of `overAllMax[arr[j]]` which is maximum value of each $1 of all files.

Answer (score 4):

Assumptions:

- multiple files are to be joined based on the contents of the 1st column
- all files have the same number of lines and the same set of values in the 1st column

One `awk` approach:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { lines[++max]=$1 }                                      # lines[] used to maintain ordering of input rows (based on first file)
        { for (i=4;i<=NF;i+=4)                                   # loop through 4th, 8th, 12th, ... columns
              rec[$1]= rec[$1] (rec[$1]=="" ? "" : OFS) $i       # append to the record for this particular 1st column
        }
END     { for (i=1;i<=max;i++)                                   # loop through indices of lines[] array
              print lines[i],rec[lines[i]]                       # print 1st column and associated rec[] entry
        }
' ./alignments/repaired_reads/*ReadsPerGene.out.tab > gene_count.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- only purpose of the `lines[]` array is to allow us to maintain the ordering of the input rows (from the 1st file)
- OP's current `sed` script removes the `ENSG` string from beginning of the 1st column but this is not reflected in the expected output; for now I'm going to ignore this operation

This generates:

```
$ cat gene_count.txt
N_unmapped 18517 124416
N_multimapping 1620 19165
N_noFeature 33275 392595
N_ambiguous 1034 20712
ENSG00000160072 0 0
ENSG00000279928 0 0
ENSG00000228037 0 0
ENSG00000142611 0 13
ENSG00000284616 0 0
ENSG00000157911 0 8
```

Comment: Thanks. I can save it as a new file by just adding `> gene_count.txt` at the end?

Comment: @melolili correct, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^(\S+)(\s+(\S+))*/\1 \3/
        H
        x
        s/((\n\S+) [^\n]*)((\n[^\n]*)*)\2([^\n]*)$/\1\5\3/
        x
        $!d
        x
        s/.//' *.out.tab
```

Reduce each line to first and last columns.

Append the  current line to the hold space.

Swap to the hold space.

Append the last column of the previously copied line to its matching line, joining on first columns.

Swap back to the pattern space.

Delete all but the last line.

On the last line swap to the hold space.

Remove the first character (which is a newline introduced by the `H` command).

Print the result.